# Using Try Catch with Get-RegValue gives error

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run a fairly simple Powershell script using Try-Catch and I'm still getting an error.

**Script**:

```
foreach ($computerName in $computerNames) {
try     {
    $ie = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $computerName.Name -Key "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" -Value Version
    if ($ie.data -eq "9.11.9600.18059") { write-host $ie.ComputerName $ie.Data }
    }
    catch { write-host $computerName.Name not found }
}
```

**Error**:

```
Get-RegValue : Exception calling "OpenRemoteBaseKey" with "2" argument(s):
"The network path was not found.
"
At line:1 char:13
+ try { $ie = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $computerName.Name -Key
"Software\Microso ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorExceptio
   n,Get-RegValue
```

Is this some limitation of PSRemoteRegistry? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Cmdlet fails really sloppily, and doesn't check if a machine is reachable before attempting to connect to it.  Not great behavior.  That being said, to trigger a try/catch block, you have to specify an -ErrorAction for the cmdlet in the block.

Change your code to this, and it will work.

```
foreach ($computerName in $computerNames) {
try     {
    $ie = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $computerName.Name -Key "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" -Value Version -ErrorAction STOP
    if ($ie.data -eq "9.11.9600.18059") { write-host $ie.ComputerName $ie.Data }
    }
    catch { write-host $computerName.Name not found }
}
```

Specifying an ErrorAction prompts PowerShell to look for user defined error handling, and will invoke your try/catch block.  Otherwise, PowerShell depends on the cmdlets themselves to handle errors.

#### If you want to emit object instead of text

to take this one Step further, emit objects instead of plain text.  Now you can dump this into Export-CSV or ConvertTo-HTML or any other cmdlet and have results that act the way things should in PowerShell.

```
foreach ($computerName in $computerNames) {
try     {
    $ie = Get-RegValue -ComputerName $computerName.Name -Key "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" -Value Version -ErrorAction STOP
    if ($ie.data -eq "9.11.9600.18059") { 
        [pscustomobject]@{ComputerName=$computerName.Name;IEVersion=$ie.Data}
        }
    }
    catch { 
    [pscustomobject]@{ComputerName=$computerName.Name;IEVersion="Offline"}
    }
}
```

Output

```
ComputerName IEVersion
------------ ---------
ham          Offline
dellbook     9.11.10547.0
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you! -erroraction is not a part of my vocabulary!

Comment: Happy to help, one other thing you might want to do is to emit PowerShell objects instead of using Write-Host statements.  Then you can run this code, and pipe it into Where-Object to filter and select only certain values.

Comment: @Nixphoe it is now :) Also check out `Get-Help about_Preference_Variables|more`, specifically the `$ErrorActionPreference` section

Comment: Added an example if emitting objects instead of plain text. Try it, you might like it!